# What should i do to load all sdcard images inside a gridview and to be able to see in full size onClick?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, gridview

I've been following some tutorials and i can achieve to get the thumbnails, but the problem is the following :

when i send the bitmap to the other activity (display activity) i get the thumbnail MINI_KIND Size, and the startup of my application takes much time than usual to launch,

What i want is :

a fast way to load all SdCard images, to display them in Grid View and when i click one of them to be able to get its file path to display in the other activity
Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show you my way to do this.

1. Using cursor to load all image path from sdcard.
2. Using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to display it.

Comment: Does it is fast ? i mean app launch to take 1-2 seconds , not like my method which goes around 15 seconds

Comment: Yes, it is. believe me. I'm using its now :)

Comment: can you provide me some sample code ? i've been searching on google but i can't find a tutorial yet

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/vnindie-training/source/browse/trunk/new-project-name/trunk/Studio-Picsafe/Picsafe/app/src/main/java/com/vnindie/picsafe/views/fragments/GalleryFragment.java

This is my project. It's out-dated but still works. If you want to see the result, you can go to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vnindie.picsafe

If you have any question, feel free to ask.

Comment: thanks so much, i've learned how to use Universal image loader and its working very well but i need a last thing, when i scroll down it loads other images fast and very well but when i scroll up it loads images again, how can i make the loaded images to remain loaded already not to load them again ?

Comment: You can cache it in memory/sdcard:

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Useful-Info

Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you. Thanks :)